# Theming with CiviCRM and Drupal, php variables, basics

Tags: drupal, drupal-themes, user-registration, drupal-forms, civicrm

I've installed CiviCRM with my drupal installation, and I am creating a custom theme.  What is a good resource for utilizing CiviCRM elements in the theme?

I need to give/pull these things to/from CiviCRM:

Registration elements, Basic CiviCRM variables, and Profile elements...

Sorry if it seems like a newbie question to some of you, but CiviCRM.org seems like it's too full of filler language...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the CiviCRM API. Try this page:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC40/CiviCRM+Public+APIs
**EDIT:** Updated link

I've never used CiviCRM, but a good resource for finding how to retrieve data from CMS modules in general is to look at the code for the module/extension/plugin itself. It will often be retrieving information the same way you can for your template.